# Excel: Transpose Like Rows into Columns

Tags: excel, transpose

I have an excel spreadsheet that has student names in the first column and then some corresponding information for that student in other columns. Student names have been changed for privacy.

[image]

You'll notice that I have multiple students in a column because there are 2 (or more) test scores in that last column.

I need to have 1 student per row so I'd like to take the other scores and make those columns. So for that first student there would be a Mean Score 1 and Mean Score 2.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for is Pivot.

[Excel Pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663063/excel-pivot)